# How to anchor a page-section to the bottom of a navigation bar that appears on scroll?

Tags: javascript, html, css, anchor, navbar

I have a single page website (Squarespace - Pacific template) https://pacific-demo.squarespace.com/?nochrome=false with a Navigation bar at the top that scrolls away with the home-page and appears again once you scroll to the first-section. All the links are anchored to the correspondent section that slides up and stops in line with the Navigation Bar that appears on scroll.

I would like to add a link to the home-page with an arrow that sends you down only to the first-section and aligns this with the appearing navigation bar.
With a simple anchor link the section scrolls to the top of the browser behind the Navbar.

I tried this script (adding one for each media-query I used) and it works, but if I resize the browser, the Navbar disappears, so I'd like to use something different.

```
 if($(window).width() < 1438)
{
$("#arrow-down").click(function() {
    $('html,body').animate({
        scrollTop: $("#officina-page").offset().top -120},
        'slow');
});
}

    else if($(window).width() > 1439 && $(window).width() < 1558)
{
   $("#arrow-down").click(function() {
    $('html,body').animate({
        scrollTop: $("#officina-page").offset().top -130},
        'slow');
});
}
```

Comment: Are you trying to do this ? https://codepen.io/nxworld/pen/OyRrGy

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this with the good offset (height of your menu):

```
if($(window).width() > 1438) {
    $(function() {
      $('a[href*=#]').on('click', function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        $('html, body').animate({ scrollTop: $($(this).attr('href')).offset().top}, 500, 'linear');
      });
    });
}
```

Comment: This would work but is I add the height of my menu to the script and resize the browser, the height changes. I don't know if it's possible, but I need to avoid that...